# Multiple Processes in Python

Tags: python, multithreading, timer, multiprocessing, interrupt

I am writing a program with an infinite while loop that runs a function which takes input from the user and then prints to the console. I would like to be able to do something along the lines of having a separate piece of code that continually checks the time as a background process and at a certain time, prints a message to the console and asks whether you'd like to quit the program or continue the while loop.
I assume I'd need multithreading or something along the lines of that.

```
def main():
    while True:
        x = input("Write Something: ")
        print(x)

main()
```

Comment: Could you clarify your question and include any code you currently have?

Comment: Why can't you do that inside the while loop?  With multithreading you will have to deal with interleaved output.

Comment: The program is kinda lengthy so I've taken it down to the basics.

What I'd like is to somehow pause the main function, 'inject' a print statment at a given time, and then ask the user whether they would like to continue with the main() function or quit the program

Comment: I can't check the time inside the main() while loop. Suppose the user got up right as the specified time was reached, the code would never execute because it would still be waiting on user input before it looped again. I need a separate process independent of the main() function that can interrupt when a certain time is reached

Answer (score 2):

Threads are good for this, and the background thread will spend most of its time sleeping.  Here's something you can start with.  You'll have lots of problems eventually - comes with the territory ;-)

```
import threading

timetoquit = False
iolock = threading.Lock()

class Watcher(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, timeout):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.timeout = timeout
        self.waiter = threading.Event()

    def run(self):
        global timetoquit
        while not timetoquit:
            self.waiter.wait(self.timeout)
            if timetoquit:
                return
            with iolock:
                i = raw_input("want to quit? ")
            if i.startswith("y") or i.startswith("Y"):
                timetoquit = True
            self.waiter.clear()

    # Unused in this example, but you may want it someday ;-)
    def cancel(self):
        global timetoquit
        timetoquit = True
        self.waiter.set()

# this Watcher will ask every 10 seconds
watch = Watcher(10)
watch.start()

while not timetoquit:
    # do stuff
    # put console interaction in `with iolock` to
    #   prevent the main program and the thread from
    #   messing with the console at the same time
    with iolock:
        if not timetoquit:
            whatever = raw_input("enter something ")
    # do stuff
```

Comment: Thank you for the prompt reply!

I apologize that I don't fully understand all of your code. I'm not the best with classes yet. I'm pretty sure from your notes, however, that it's supposed to prompt me after 10 seconds to quit or contine. The 'enter something' part runs fine but it never does anything other than that.

Comment: The thread should ask you `want to quit?` **every** 10 seconds.  Don't run it in (for example) Idle.  "Development environments" very often don't play well with threads or with multiprocessing.  Run it from a command shell.  BTW, I tested it with Python 2.7.5, but that shouldn't matter.

Comment: Also, you have to **respond** to the "enter something" prompts.  The whole purpose of `iolock` is to **stop** the thread and the main program from messing with the console input/output at the same time.  That would be a real mess ;-)  Just keep hitting ENTER.

Comment: But it's not a video game either - LOL ;-)  I mean if you keep hitting ENTER quickly, the thread won't get a chance to run.  Wait a second or two.

Comment: I had been running it in Idle. I'm on a mac and I just opened it in the terminal but got the same results.

Comment: I don't have a Mac, but that shouldn't matter either.  Time to add some `print` statements to see whether the thread is running at all.  Etc.  Welcome to the wonderful world of multiprocessing ;-)

Comment: I got it to say 'want to quit?' but only after holding down the enter key for while. Of course I blew right passed it ;-) Is there any way for it to not need any user interaction though. Like have it ask if you want to quit regardless of whether you've hit enter yet or not?

Comment: What I'm basically working on is an experimental Artificial Intelligence program and I'd like to give it an alarm clock feature. So you can set a certain time and then continue to talk with it, or you can get up and walk away, but regardless at the set time a function will pause the current process and execute whatever it contains

Comment: Things become an intractable mess if you want **both** the main program **and** a thread (or another process) to spray messages to the console, and ask for input, at the same time.  You have to hit ENTER now because the main program **is** asking for input.  The main program here is just a toy.  Do you expect your real main program to be forever waiting for input too?  If so, this approach won't work well.

Comment: Sorry, I'm out of time for today.  Python's `threading.Timer()` function can be used to run a user-supplied function after a specified amount of time has passed.  Maybe that would suit you better - can't guess.  Look at the docs :-)

Comment: I think a [GIL battle](http://www.dabeaz.com/GIL/) is going on.
When I run this code on Ubuntu, the `"want to quit?"` message is virtually never printed (*unless* I press and hold the Enter key to make it autorepeat). I think the reason for this has to do with the main thread's `while-loop` being so tight that the OS's thread scheduler is virtually always letting the main thread get to `with iolock` before the `Watcher` thread getting to `with iolock`. 
I was able to avoid the problem by putting `time.sleep(0)` inside the main thread's `while-loop`.

Comment: Yup, that should help a lot :-)

Answer (score 1):

Here is an attempt using Tim Peters' suggestion to use `threading.Timer`:

```
import threading

check_done = False
def are_we_done_yet():
    global check_done
    print("quit now?")
    check_done = True
    t = threading.Timer(2.0, are_we_done_yet)
    t.daemon = True
    t.start()

t = threading.Timer(2.0, are_we_done_yet)
t.daemon = True
t.start()

while True:
    response = raw_input('>>> ')
    if check_done:
        if response.lower().startswith('y'): break
        check_done = False
```

---

One problem with the code above is that there is no way to distinguish input that the user intended for the `>>>` prompt from the user's response to the question `quit now?`.

If the user happened to be typing a sentence beginning with a `y` when the `quit now?` question pops up, then the user might unintentionally cause the program to quit.

So a cleaner solution might be to use a GUI:

```
import Tkinter as tk
import tkMessageBox
def are_we_done_yet():
    if tkMessageBox.askyesno(title="Quit", message="Quit now?",
                             default=tkMessageBox.NO):
        root.quit()
    root.after(2000, are_we_done_yet)

root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry('300x200')
entry = tk.Text(root)
entry.pack()
entry.focus()
root.after(2000, are_we_done_yet)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: I'm not yet clear on what the OP wants to do, exactly.  Using a different window (like your second approach) is best if he really wants to do what we think he wants ;-)  But what a horrid UI :-(  If a user wants to quit, they can just stop the program - prompting them over & over would sure be annoying to me ;-)